# d3-v6-tip: d3.event is not defined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add tooltip to my map when `mouseOver` event occurs. The goal of the `mouseOver` function is that it will highlights the path and also show the tip.

I am using [d3-v6-tip](https://github.com/bumbeishvili/d3-v6-tip)

This is how I select my svg and calls the tip function

```
var svg = d3.select("#mapDiv")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("background-color", "white")
    .style("border", "solid 1px black")
    .call(d3.zoom()
        .on("zoom", function (event) {
            svg.attr("transform", event.transform);
        })
        .scaleExtent([1, 1])
    )
    .append("g");

const tip = d3.tip().attr('class', 'd3-tip').html(function (event, d) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
    return event.target.id;
});

svg.call(tip);
```

This is how I draw my map:

```
d3.json(path).then(function (json) {
    var projection = d3.geoMercator();
    var features = json.features;

    var fixed = features.map(function (feature) {
        return turf.rewind(feature, { reverse: true });
    })

    var geoPath = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

    projection.fitSize([width, height], { "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": fixed })

    svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(fixed)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", geoPath)
        .attr("id", function (d) { return d.properties.FIPS_10_; })
        .style("fill", "red")
        .style("stroke", "transparent")
        .on("mouseover", mouseOver)
        .on("mouseleave", mouseLeave)
        .on("click", mouseClick)
})
```

How I call tip.show in my mouseOver function:

```
let mouseOver = function (event, d) {
    var countryCode = event.target.__data__.properties.FIPS_10_;  
    d3.selectAll("path#" + countryCode)
        .transition()
        .duration(200)
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .style("stroke", "black")

    tip.show(event, d);

}
```

The problem: I put a `console.log` in my tip declaration. When my mouse hover over it, it shows the current country name in the console(`event.target.id`). However, the tooltip never show up due to the error: `Uncaught TypeError: d3.event is undefined`.

I am not completely sure if this has to do with the library itself because the source code calls `d3.event` when d3.event no longer exist in d3.v6 or am I doing something wrong in my code

Also, is there a better way to create tooltip than using the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downgraded my D3 version to 5 and now it worked. I think there is a problem with the D3-v6-tip library, not sure why.

Comment: This worked for me, but then I found that what I was doing wrong was 1) not following the new API properly: tip.html and tip.show need the 'event' passed first e.g. 'function (event, d) {...}' not just 'd'. And 2) because I was importing d3 and d3-tip to use in React, I needed to make d3 available to the window:  if (typeof window !== "undefined") { window.d3 = d3 } . Hope that helps someone like me, who really appreciates this great little simple and elegant tooltip which I've used so much over the years.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this too. I was importing d3 and d3-tip via NPM to use in my Next/React app.

1. The 'd3 is not defined' error is because d3 is not globally available on the `window` object. If importing d3 and d3-tip via NPM, make d3 available to the window. Put this in your code:

   `if (typeof window !== "undefined") { window.d3 = d3 }`
2. Make sure you are following the new v6 API properly: calls to `tip.html()` and `tip.show()` need the `event` passed first before the data e.g.

   `function (event, d) {...}`

   not just `d`. That's why downgrading to v5 as per the OP's suggestion worked for me at first - I wasn't doing that. And that would also explain why the Tooltip was failing to position properly.

I hope that helps someone struggling like I was. I really appreciate this great little trusty, simple and elegant tooltip which I've used extensively over the years, and the efforts of the various forkers and maintainers to keep it compatible with the latest d3 versions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're just missing the step to invoke the tip.

Check the code underneath where the page says [*'If you want to load it as standalone...'*](https://github.com/bumbeishvili/d3-v6-tip) :

```
/* Invoke the tip in the context of your visualization */
svg.call(tip)
```

Your event handler code otherwise seems to work fine per this adaptation:

```js
const width = 200;
const height = 200;
const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);
  
const tip = d3.tip()
  .attr("class", "d3-tip")
  .html((event, d) => event.target.id); 
  
const projection = d3.geoMercator();
const mapJson = roi();
const features = mapJson.features; 
const geoPath = d3.geoPath()
  .projection(projection);

projection.fitSize([width, height], mapJson);

svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(features)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", geoPath)
  .attr("id", d => d.properties.id)
  .style("fill", "green")
  .style("stroke", "red")
  .on("mouseover", mouseOver)
  .on("mouseleave", mouseLeave)
  .on("click", mouseClick)
  .call(tip);
  
function mouseOver(event, d) {
  d3.selectAll(`path#${event.target.id}`)
    .transition()
    .duration(200)
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .style("stroke", "white");
  tip.show(event, d);
}

function mouseLeave(event, d) {
  d3.selectAll(`path#${event.target.id}`)
    .transition()
    .duration(200)
    .style("stroke", "red");
  tip.hide()
}

function mouseClick(event, d) {
  window.alert(`Selected ${d.properties.id}`);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-v6-tip@1.0.6/build/d3-v6-tip.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/bumbeishvili/d3-tip-for-v6@4/d3-tip.min.css">
<script>
function roi() {
  return {
    "type": "FeatureCollection", 
    "features": [
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Carlow" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.592415, 52.708085 ], [ -6.614788, 52.654218 ], [ -6.717890, 52.633128 ], [ -6.810019, 52.481218 ], [ -6.916185, 52.446304 ], [ -6.914688, 52.590519 ], [ -6.975609, 52.653791 ], [ -6.952951, 52.705377 ], [ -7.090468, 52.732311 ], [ -7.072441, 52.797934 ], [ -7.065957, 52.822872 ], [ -6.915828, 52.856717 ], [ -6.735489, 52.884007 ], [ -6.712332, 52.924335 ], [ -6.463234, 52.893982 ], [ -6.512470, 52.826791 ], [ -6.631176, 52.831494 ], [ -6.592415, 52.708085 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": {  "id": "Cavan" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -7.311848, 54.114105 ], [ -7.188226, 54.079548 ], [ -7.035960, 54.086530 ], [ -6.753231, 53.901916 ], [ -6.753302, 53.900348 ], [ -6.779095, 53.873842 ], [ -6.942976, 53.874982 ], [ -6.955730, 53.766893 ], [ -7.275153, 53.783851 ], [ -7.282350, 53.795394 ], [ -7.394715, 53.781713 ], [ -7.471810, 53.835936 ], [ -7.577762, 53.872702 ], [ -7.606476, 53.937257 ], [ -7.604552, 54.005160 ], [ -7.760239, 54.105127 ], [ -7.853223, 54.098144 ], [ -8.034560, 54.238796 ], [ -7.952976, 54.306628 ], [ -7.878090, 54.289172 ], [ -7.820589, 54.199180 ], [ -7.696967, 54.202529 ], [ -7.554248, 54.127999 ], [ -7.414737, 54.150800 ], [ -7.311848, 54.114105 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Clare" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -9.014420, 53.143721 ], [ -8.995325, 53.094486 ], [ -8.898707, 53.061852 ], [ -8.825673, 52.973357 ], [ -8.610278, 53.039336 ], [ -8.448392, 52.981622 ], [ -8.301399, 53.004138 ], [ -8.315365, 52.923338 ], [ -8.415403, 52.895906 ], [ -8.486797, 52.717419 ], [ -8.542089, 52.683432 ], [ -8.736394, 52.676235 ], [ -8.862510, 52.697896 ], [ -8.966396, 52.683717 ], [ -8.941957, 52.735161 ], [ -9.043064, 52.749839 ], [ -9.077478, 52.671817 ], [ -9.162482, 52.618450 ], [ -9.417494, 52.602062 ], [ -9.546959, 52.639326 ], [ -9.700864, 52.612108 ], [ -9.696375, 52.582325 ], [ -9.939203, 52.558170 ], [ -9.650845, 52.677945 ], [ -9.613081, 52.742927 ], [ -9.495800, 52.750694 ], [ -9.446422, 52.877095 ], [ -9.347524, 52.929893 ], [ -9.476420, 52.941507 ], [ -9.392484, 53.007914 ], [ -9.282471, 53.145146 ], [ -9.152507, 53.119566 ], [ -9.127497, 53.157615 ], [ -9.014420, 53.143721 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Cork" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -8.160320, 52.302731 ], [ -8.088569, 52.215518 ], [ -8.137519, 52.159086 ], [ -7.927468, 51.990147 ], [ -7.849731, 51.978747 ], [ -7.904168, 51.911271 ], [ -7.865834, 51.880134 ], [ -7.997508, 51.860682 ], [ -8.001356, 51.825127 ], [ -8.170295, 51.784300 ], [ -8.264704, 51.815152 ], [ -8.202501, 51.874006 ], [ -8.319711, 51.842370 ], [ -8.273041, 51.798194 ], [ -8.339163, 51.716254 ], [ -8.563037, 51.639302 ], [ -8.658587, 51.634029 ], [ -8.706397, 51.570686 ], [ -8.867498, 51.576243 ], [ -9.107476, 51.537340 ], [ -9.227536, 51.479839 ], [ -9.535274, 51.529003 ], [ -9.644717, 51.520382 ], [ -9.773613, 51.446564 ], [ -9.838025, 51.483188 ], [ -9.653624, 51.542897 ], [ -9.539193, 51.612083 ], [ -9.850850, 51.542897 ], [ -9.444142, 51.692384 ], [ -9.451909, 51.731502 ], [ -9.639730, 51.675426 ], [ -9.906925, 51.652056 ], [ -9.935284, 51.614292 ], [ -10.166355, 51.580447 ], [ -10.055843, 51.632105 ], [ -10.097525, 51.671223 ], [ -9.974188, 51.685402 ], [ -10.004755, 51.719318 ], [ -9.908279, 51.749600 ], [ -9.856336, 51.719175 ], [ -9.727869, 51.792636 ], [ -9.595054, 51.796698 ], [ -9.330922, 51.890181 ], [ -9.305343, 51.970553 ], [ -9.153718, 52.007676 ], [ -9.229317, 52.180890 ], [ -9.294513, 52.237036 ], [ -9.234589, 52.308431 ], [ -9.132414, 52.338500 ], [ -8.961836, 52.321185 ], [ -8.842702, 52.378330 ], [ -8.640631, 52.360160 ], [ -8.519502, 52.284704 ], [ -8.341799, 52.321969 ], [ -8.160320, 52.302731 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": {  "id": "Donegal" } , "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -8.541947, 55.023711 ], [ -8.486370, 54.973478 ], [ -8.569735, 54.975687 ], [ -8.541947, 55.023711 ] ] ], [ [ [ -8.161674, 54.457683 ], [ -8.282019, 54.479843 ], [ -8.223093, 54.572114 ], [ -8.109161, 54.612657 ], [ -8.115787, 54.649922 ], [ -8.299190, 54.600971 ], [ -8.288075, 54.646502 ], [ -8.463070, 54.605175 ], [ -8.586978, 54.605674 ], [ -8.793609, 54.659042 ], [ -8.807504, 54.697661 ], [ -8.653100, 54.775682 ], [ -8.434142, 54.755446 ], [ -8.568595, 54.825701 ], [ -8.384194, 54.882631 ], [ -8.460292, 54.918756 ], [ -8.462999, 55.002691 ], [ -8.348639, 55.039030 ], [ -8.286365, 55.159945 ], [ -8.159750, 55.146550 ], [ -8.026366, 55.173483 ], [ -7.981405, 55.227635 ], [ -7.873601, 55.202055 ], [ -7.631913, 55.278224 ], [ -7.617520, 55.191225 ], [ -7.517482, 55.122609 ], [ -7.633623, 55.057698 ], [ -7.559165, 55.034327 ], [ -7.680864, 54.951817 ], [ -7.472522, 55.046511 ], [ -7.526959, 55.059052 ], [ -7.462476, 55.137358 ], [ -7.555816, 55.197067 ], [ -7.528028, 55.285990 ], [ -7.428631, 55.279577 ], [ -7.348116, 55.357884 ], [ -7.194710, 55.348193 ], [ -7.153597, 55.294825 ], [ -6.920745, 55.237111 ], [ -7.158585, 55.148758 ], [ -7.273871, 55.056772 ], [ -7.353103, 55.048649 ], [ -7.443024, 54.934432 ], [ -7.457987, 54.857907 ], [ -7.552467, 54.791714 ], [ -7.537362, 54.744758 ], [ -7.648658, 54.749532 ], [ -7.750619, 54.705498 ], [ -7.834412, 54.738559 ], [ -7.925259, 54.702292 ], [ -7.855289, 54.634674 ], [ -7.710647, 54.630327 ], [ -7.829211, 54.544682 ], [ -8.003280, 54.546107 ], [ -8.052729, 54.489675 ], [ -8.161674, 54.457683 ] ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Dublin" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.105263, 53.219391 ], [ -6.347948, 53.200936 ], [ -6.464161, 53.228939 ], [ -6.535199, 53.255302 ], [ -6.495512, 53.384126 ], [ -6.453473, 53.376858 ], [ -6.334767, 53.452528 ], [ -6.320516, 53.495493 ], [ -6.408085, 53.563468 ], [ -6.291089, 53.579998 ], [ -6.213638, 53.635504 ], [ -6.098637, 53.585128 ], [ -6.075836, 53.519006 ], [ -6.121936, 53.388757 ], [ -6.229171, 53.360470 ], [ -6.100276, 53.282877 ], [ -6.105263, 53.219391 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Galway" } , "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -9.780809, 53.152057 ], [ -9.654194, 53.131822 ], [ -9.654194, 53.088500 ], [ -9.830258, 53.138163 ], [ -9.780809, 53.152057 ] ] ], [ [ [ -9.630823, 53.320711 ], [ -9.648066, 53.227371 ], [ -9.744185, 53.235138 ], [ -9.630823, 53.320711 ] ] ], [ [ [ -8.020095, 53.261501 ], [ -7.956538, 53.216256 ], [ -8.068404, 53.175642 ], [ -8.301399, 53.004138 ], [ -8.448392, 52.981622 ], [ -8.610278, 53.039336 ], [ -8.825673, 52.973357 ], [ -8.898707, 53.061852 ], [ -8.995325, 53.094486 ], [ -9.014420, 53.143721 ], [ -8.903053, 53.221528 ], [ -9.051970, 53.220175 ], [ -8.936399, 53.271547 ], [ -9.525869, 53.220958 ], [ -9.622487, 53.326269 ], [ -9.550807, 53.342372 ], [ -9.649135, 53.387119 ], [ -9.774753, 53.291498 ], [ -9.908065, 53.328763 ], [ -10.071946, 53.420678 ], [ -10.198062, 53.405145 ], [ -10.093036, 53.467063 ], [ -10.130800, 53.574868 ], [ -10.014160, 53.567885 ], [ -10.056413, 53.611492 ], [ -9.669727, 53.614912 ], [ -9.610587, 53.632725 ], [ -9.409727, 53.541095 ], [ -9.265798, 53.544301 ], [ -9.203239, 53.487442 ], [ -9.117023, 53.486800 ], [ -8.983425, 53.621895 ], [ -8.814985, 53.663292 ], [ -8.664358, 53.670916 ], [ -8.611489, 53.709535 ], [ -8.438631, 53.687660 ], [ -8.263208, 53.516085 ], [ -8.242046, 53.361040 ], [ -8.152838, 53.328478 ], [ -8.129753, 53.262427 ], [ -8.020095, 53.261501 ] ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Kerry" } , "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -10.349188, 51.935996 ], [ -10.286415, 51.921817 ], [ -10.430843, 51.880134 ], [ -10.349188, 51.935996 ] ] ], [ [ [ -9.328215, 52.572634 ], [ -9.303134, 52.515490 ], [ -9.339544, 52.373057 ], [ -9.234589, 52.308431 ], [ -9.294513, 52.237036 ], [ -9.229317, 52.180890 ], [ -9.153718, 52.007676 ], [ -9.305343, 51.970553 ], [ -9.330922, 51.890181 ], [ -9.595054, 51.796698 ], [ -9.727869, 51.792636 ], [ -9.856336, 51.719175 ], [ -9.908279, 51.749600 ], [ -9.863034, 51.748175 ], [ -9.745824, 51.849282 ], [ -10.125812, 51.736775 ], [ -10.228059, 51.781806 ], [ -10.208607, 51.844009 ], [ -10.343630, 51.782946 ], [ -10.335864, 51.845434 ], [ -10.408612, 51.878495 ], [ -10.252499, 51.904004 ], [ -10.321970, 51.952669 ], [ -10.258056, 51.991786 ], [ -9.916972, 52.066815 ], [ -9.889184, 52.111276 ], [ -9.753021, 52.156806 ], [ -9.985303, 52.143197 ], [ -10.193074, 52.106787 ], [ -10.287484, 52.140418 ], [ -10.452504, 52.096527 ], [ -10.475803, 52.176828 ], [ -10.361372, 52.235398 ], [ -10.178040, 52.291544 ], [ -10.181959, 52.231265 ], [ -10.026415, 52.271522 ], [ -9.955804, 52.232619 ], [ -9.736419, 52.256773 ], [ -9.876928, 52.274016 ], [ -9.833607, 52.385669 ], [ -9.943620, 52.422933 ], [ -9.828049, 52.434334 ], [ -9.687469, 52.482928 ], [ -9.620278, 52.581541 ], [ -9.364197, 52.591231 ], [ -9.328215, 52.572634 ] ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Kildare" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.495512, 53.384126 ], [ -6.535199, 53.255302 ], [ -6.464161, 53.228939 ], [ -6.592771, 53.092704 ], [ -6.745464, 53.017747 ], [ -6.712332, 52.924335 ], [ -6.735489, 52.884007 ], [ -6.915828, 52.856717 ], [ -6.957939, 52.967443 ], [ -7.032896, 52.971932 ], [ -7.030687, 53.080235 ], [ -7.097237, 53.164598 ], [ -6.997626, 53.317006 ], [ -7.136140, 53.409563 ], [ -7.032112, 53.514019 ], [ -6.840586, 53.390539 ], [ -6.713757, 53.426378 ], [ -6.495512, 53.384126 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Kilkenny" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -7.072441, 52.797934 ], [ -7.090468, 52.732311 ], [ -6.952951, 52.705377 ], [ -6.975609, 52.653791 ], [ -6.914688, 52.590519 ], [ -6.916185, 52.446304 ], [ -6.975182, 52.291544 ], [ -7.191717, 52.251857 ], [ -7.338853, 52.342561 ], [ -7.400130, 52.455496 ], [ -7.386663, 52.502451 ], [ -7.454139, 52.640253 ], [ -7.649370, 52.790809 ], [ -7.559236, 52.834771 ], [ -7.414737, 52.792305 ], [ -7.284772, 52.865624 ], [ -7.181172, 52.893412 ], [ -7.065957, 52.822872 ], [ -7.072441, 52.797934 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Laois" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -7.097237, 53.164598 ], [ -7.030687, 53.080235 ], [ -7.032896, 52.971932 ], [ -6.957939, 52.967443 ], [ -6.915828, 52.856717 ], [ -7.065957, 52.822872 ], [ -7.181172, 52.893412 ], [ -7.284772, 52.865624 ], [ -7.414737, 52.792305 ], [ -7.559236, 52.834771 ], [ -7.649370, 52.790809 ], [ -7.686564, 52.851444 ], [ -7.656923, 52.939370 ], [ -7.692264, 52.982335 ], [ -7.555246, 53.100115 ], [ -7.617948, 53.144790 ], [ -7.541708, 53.181271 ], [ -7.354813, 53.202647 ], [ -7.265606, 53.140230 ], [ -7.097237, 53.164598 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Leitrim" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -8.282019, 54.479843 ], [ -8.161674, 54.457683 ], [ -7.952976, 54.306628 ], [ -8.034560, 54.238796 ], [ -7.853223, 54.098144 ], [ -7.760239, 54.105127 ], [ -7.604552, 54.005160 ], [ -7.606476, 53.937257 ], [ -7.663122, 53.937114 ], [ -7.822370, 53.819477 ], [ -7.899109, 53.815558 ], [ -8.000359, 53.926712 ], [ -8.100895, 53.953859 ], [ -8.040972, 54.077125 ], [ -8.133671, 54.101422 ], [ -8.170794, 54.102633 ], [ -8.333463, 54.185500 ], [ -8.310591, 54.272855 ], [ -8.377782, 54.348453 ], [ -8.373863, 54.468228 ], [ -8.282019, 54.479843 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Limerick" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -8.160320, 52.302731 ], [ -8.341799, 52.321969 ], [ -8.519502, 52.284704 ], [ -8.640631, 52.360160 ], [ -8.842702, 52.378330 ], [ -8.961836, 52.321185 ], [ -9.132414, 52.338500 ], [ -9.234589, 52.308431 ], [ -9.339544, 52.373057 ], [ -9.303134, 52.515490 ], [ -9.328215, 52.572634 ], [ -8.987487, 52.619305 ], [ -8.958060, 52.660702 ], [ -8.638066, 52.660702 ], [ -8.736394, 52.676235 ], [ -8.542089, 52.683432 ], [ -8.486797, 52.717419 ], [ -8.358258, 52.682648 ], [ -8.257080, 52.697682 ], [ -8.180698, 52.666545 ], [ -8.197941, 52.521333 ], [ -8.399157, 52.468464 ], [ -8.388968, 52.438751 ], [ -8.230361, 52.404265 ], [ -8.160320, 52.302731 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Longford" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -7.471810, 53.835936 ], [ -7.394715, 53.781713 ], [ -7.390725, 53.735827 ], [ -7.591442, 53.647545 ], [ -7.658348, 53.531119 ], [ -7.846454, 53.538601 ], [ -7.952620, 53.512380 ], [ -8.025938, 53.607359 ], [ -7.978912, 53.694999 ], [ -7.887424, 53.772237 ], [ -7.899109, 53.815558 ], [ -7.822370, 53.819477 ], [ -7.663122, 53.937114 ], [ -7.606476, 53.937257 ], [ -7.577762, 53.872702 ], [ -7.471810, 53.835936 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Louth" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.238576, 53.778721 ], [ -6.339042, 53.722788 ], [ -6.481475, 53.722788 ], [ -6.561562, 53.771453 ], [ -6.616427, 53.861516 ], [ -6.687038, 53.875481 ], [ -6.753302, 53.900348 ], [ -6.753231, 53.901916 ], [ -6.679699, 53.909469 ], [ -6.584434, 54.051902 ], [ -6.470146, 54.078835 ], [ -6.374739, 54.066366 ], [ -6.279760, 54.109901 ], [ -6.100846, 53.999603 ], [ -6.164688, 53.976802 ], [ -6.352508, 54.011502 ], [ -6.377518, 53.955711 ], [ -6.333627, 53.877049 ], [ -6.238576, 53.861801 ], [ -6.238576, 53.778721 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Mayo" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -9.138043, 54.130707 ], [ -8.963404, 54.145527 ], [ -9.027317, 54.030241 ], [ -8.913598, 54.017701 ], [ -8.835078, 53.972455 ], [ -8.661294, 54.025681 ], [ -8.590398, 53.968109 ], [ -8.682599, 53.958704 ], [ -8.608211, 53.885884 ], [ -8.690223, 53.874484 ], [ -8.696279, 53.722716 ], [ -8.814985, 53.663292 ], [ -8.983425, 53.621895 ], [ -9.117023, 53.486800 ], [ -9.203239, 53.487442 ], [ -9.265798, 53.544301 ], [ -9.409727, 53.541095 ], [ -9.610587, 53.632725 ], [ -9.669727, 53.614912 ], [ -9.774183, 53.600661 ], [ -9.915832, 53.656238 ], [ -9.912483, 53.752286 ], [ -9.651272, 53.800453 ], [ -9.554084, 53.889874 ], [ -9.764706, 53.900134 ], [ -9.905857, 53.861231 ], [ -10.066388, 53.971814 ], [ -10.259196, 53.973453 ], [ -10.189155, 54.015706 ], [ -10.100803, 54.000671 ], [ -9.974188, 54.030669 ], [ -9.966421, 53.951009 ], [ -9.838025, 53.960414 ], [ -9.993639, 54.102633 ], [ -9.899729, 54.117953 ], [ -10.012521, 54.226541 ], [ -10.010312, 54.181296 ], [ -10.129161, 54.096007 ], [ -10.055843, 54.218204 ], [ -10.109709, 54.238511 ], [ -9.995777, 54.309336 ], [ -9.880277, 54.257607 ], [ -9.805819, 54.344606 ], [ -9.382509, 54.294302 ], [ -9.341967, 54.327363 ], [ -9.211931, 54.285894 ], [ -9.224187, 54.217136 ], [ -9.159703, 54.201816 ], [ -9.138043, 54.130707 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Meath" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.687038, 53.875481 ], [ -6.616427, 53.861516 ], [ -6.561562, 53.771453 ], [ -6.481475, 53.722788 ], [ -6.339042, 53.722788 ], [ -6.238576, 53.778721 ], [ -6.213638, 53.635504 ], [ -6.291089, 53.579998 ], [ -6.408085, 53.563468 ], [ -6.320516, 53.495493 ], [ -6.334767, 53.452528 ], [ -6.453473, 53.376858 ], [ -6.495512, 53.384126 ], [ -6.713757, 53.426378 ], [ -6.840586, 53.390539 ], [ -7.032112, 53.514019 ], [ -6.962926, 53.639494 ], [ -7.250928, 53.711387 ], [ -7.275153, 53.783851 ], [ -6.955730, 53.766893 ], [ -6.942976, 53.874982 ], [ -6.779095, 53.873842 ], [ -6.753302, 53.900348 ], [ -6.687038, 53.875481 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Monaghan" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.584434, 54.051902 ], [ -6.679699, 53.909469 ], [ -6.753231, 53.901916 ], [ -7.035960, 54.086530 ], [ -7.188226, 54.079548 ], [ -7.311848, 54.114105 ], [ -7.237746, 54.203455 ], [ -7.142268, 54.227325 ], [ -7.202120, 54.297722 ], [ -7.025129, 54.416143 ], [ -6.876141, 54.345247 ], [ -6.795555, 54.211649 ], [ -6.636377, 54.172745 ], [ -6.670293, 54.070570 ], [ -6.584434, 54.051902 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Offaly" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.997626, 53.317006 ], [ -7.097237, 53.164598 ], [ -7.265606, 53.140230 ], [ -7.354813, 53.202647 ], [ -7.541708, 53.181271 ], [ -7.617948, 53.144790 ], [ -7.555246, 53.100115 ], [ -7.692264, 52.982335 ], [ -7.822513, 52.956256 ], [ -7.922337, 52.862560 ], [ -8.013326, 52.909729 ], [ -7.956681, 52.952907 ], [ -7.904738, 53.092491 ], [ -8.068404, 53.175642 ], [ -7.956538, 53.216256 ], [ -8.020095, 53.261501 ], [ -8.021734, 53.303326 ], [ -7.915640, 53.353416 ], [ -7.767649, 53.329048 ], [ -7.586953, 53.383770 ], [ -7.535224, 53.333751 ], [ -7.372769, 53.317719 ], [ -7.337927, 53.350709 ], [ -7.136140, 53.409563 ], [ -6.997626, 53.317006 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Roscommon" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -8.133671, 54.101422 ], [ -8.040972, 54.077125 ], [ -8.100895, 53.953859 ], [ -8.000359, 53.926712 ], [ -7.899109, 53.815558 ], [ -7.887424, 53.772237 ], [ -7.978912, 53.694999 ], [ -8.025938, 53.607359 ], [ -7.952620, 53.512380 ], [ -7.915640, 53.353416 ], [ -8.021734, 53.303326 ], [ -8.020095, 53.261501 ], [ -8.129753, 53.262427 ], [ -8.152838, 53.328478 ], [ -8.242046, 53.361040 ], [ -8.263208, 53.516085 ], [ -8.438631, 53.687660 ], [ -8.611489, 53.709535 ], [ -8.664358, 53.670916 ], [ -8.814985, 53.663292 ], [ -8.696279, 53.722716 ], [ -8.690223, 53.874484 ], [ -8.608211, 53.885884 ], [ -8.682599, 53.958704 ], [ -8.590398, 53.968109 ], [ -8.459722, 53.916024 ], [ -8.373008, 53.919088 ], [ -8.275606, 54.047627 ], [ -8.170794, 54.102633 ], [ -8.133671, 54.101422 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Sligo" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -8.373863, 54.468228 ], [ -8.377782, 54.348453 ], [ -8.310591, 54.272855 ], [ -8.333463, 54.185500 ], [ -8.170794, 54.102633 ], [ -8.275606, 54.047627 ], [ -8.373008, 53.919088 ], [ -8.459722, 53.916024 ], [ -8.590398, 53.968109 ], [ -8.661294, 54.025681 ], [ -8.835078, 53.972455 ], [ -8.913598, 54.017701 ], [ -9.027317, 54.030241 ], [ -8.963404, 54.145527 ], [ -9.138043, 54.130707 ], [ -9.057528, 54.295442 ], [ -8.930271, 54.294302 ], [ -8.827526, 54.253474 ], [ -8.661935, 54.272641 ], [ -8.583629, 54.207944 ], [ -8.508601, 54.217349 ], [ -8.626381, 54.255113 ], [ -8.681886, 54.355935 ], [ -8.490289, 54.418209 ], [ -8.469697, 54.470437 ], [ -8.373863, 54.468228 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Tipperary" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -8.013326, 52.909729 ], [ -7.922337, 52.862560 ], [ -7.822513, 52.956256 ], [ -7.692264, 52.982335 ], [ -7.656923, 52.939370 ], [ -7.686564, 52.851444 ], [ -7.649370, 52.790809 ], [ -7.454139, 52.640253 ], [ -7.386663, 52.502451 ], [ -7.400130, 52.455496 ], [ -7.338853, 52.342561 ], [ -7.545271, 52.355671 ], [ -7.760524, 52.314986 ], [ -7.722190, 52.222216 ], [ -7.944426, 52.236466 ], [ -8.088569, 52.215518 ], [ -8.160320, 52.302731 ], [ -8.230361, 52.404265 ], [ -8.388968, 52.438751 ], [ -8.399157, 52.468464 ], [ -8.197941, 52.521333 ], [ -8.180698, 52.666545 ], [ -8.257080, 52.697682 ], [ -8.358258, 52.682648 ], [ -8.486797, 52.717419 ], [ -8.415403, 52.895906 ], [ -8.315365, 52.923338 ], [ -8.301399, 53.004138 ], [ -8.068404, 53.175642 ], [ -7.904738, 53.092491 ], [ -7.956681, 52.952907 ], [ -8.013326, 52.909729 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Waterford" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -7.545271, 52.355671 ], [ -7.338853, 52.342561 ], [ -7.191717, 52.251857 ], [ -6.975182, 52.291544 ], [ -6.958651, 52.241525 ], [ -6.949175, 52.177612 ], [ -7.019714, 52.134006 ], [ -7.088615, 52.150679 ], [ -7.426921, 52.129588 ], [ -7.551398, 52.077645 ], [ -7.585243, 51.991501 ], [ -7.731951, 51.937635 ], [ -7.849731, 51.978747 ], [ -7.927468, 51.990147 ], [ -8.137519, 52.159086 ], [ -8.088569, 52.215518 ], [ -7.944426, 52.236466 ], [ -7.722190, 52.222216 ], [ -7.760524, 52.314986 ], [ -7.545271, 52.355671 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Westmeath" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -7.282350, 53.795394 ], [ -7.275153, 53.783851 ], [ -7.250928, 53.711387 ], [ -6.962926, 53.639494 ], [ -7.032112, 53.514019 ], [ -7.136140, 53.409563 ], [ -7.337927, 53.350709 ], [ -7.372769, 53.317719 ], [ -7.535224, 53.333751 ], [ -7.586953, 53.383770 ], [ -7.767649, 53.329048 ], [ -7.915640, 53.353416 ], [ -7.952620, 53.512380 ], [ -7.846454, 53.538601 ], [ -7.658348, 53.531119 ], [ -7.591442, 53.647545 ], [ -7.390725, 53.735827 ], [ -7.394715, 53.781713 ], [ -7.282350, 53.795394 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Wexford" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.958651, 52.241525 ], [ -6.975182, 52.291544 ], [ -6.916185, 52.446304 ], [ -6.810019, 52.481218 ], [ -6.717890, 52.633128 ], [ -6.614788, 52.654218 ], [ -6.592415, 52.708085 ], [ -6.446419, 52.698466 ], [ -6.325575, 52.799145 ], [ -6.144666, 52.770716 ], [ -6.225822, 52.648447 ], [ -6.193046, 52.562944 ], [ -6.353577, 52.408469 ], [ -6.358066, 52.344271 ], [ -6.465799, 52.377902 ], [ -6.429176, 52.293753 ], [ -6.311396, 52.240955 ], [ -6.358636, 52.174049 ], [ -6.489170, 52.190722 ], [ -6.596975, 52.169561 ], [ -6.706917, 52.217656 ], [ -6.836382, 52.216801 ], [ -6.823058, 52.174833 ], [ -6.931361, 52.122392 ], [ -6.903644, 52.201268 ], [ -6.958651, 52.241525 ] ] ] } },
      { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "id": "Wicklow" } , "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -6.347948, 53.200936 ], [ -6.105263, 53.219391 ], [ -6.041421, 53.117928 ], [ -6.046409, 52.989887 ], [ -5.996960, 52.963738 ], [ -6.057524, 52.857358 ], [ -6.144666, 52.770716 ], [ -6.325575, 52.799145 ], [ -6.446419, 52.698466 ], [ -6.592415, 52.708085 ], [ -6.631176, 52.831494 ], [ -6.512470, 52.826791 ], [ -6.463234, 52.893982 ], [ -6.712332, 52.924335 ], [ -6.745464, 53.017747 ], [ -6.592771, 53.092704 ], [ -6.464161, 53.228939 ], [ -6.347948, 53.200936 ] ] ] } }
    ]
  }
}
</script>
```

Regarding a 'better way', IMO it would depend on if you had specific use cases not covered by the library. Also, consider the [amount of work](https://github.com/bumbeishvili/d3-v6-tip/tree/master/src) already done for us by the library which they took the time to update for D3 v6.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was able to make it work on jsfiddle, but when I literally copy the exact same code to my web site, I am still getting the same error https://jsfiddle.net/2ukpa84c/3/

Comment: To add to what I have: the tip does show up, but it is show up on the top left corner of my screen instead of where the path is. And I am still getting the same error at line `var targetel = target || d3.event.target`, I am not sure why `d3.event` is still used when d3v6 does not support global event anymore.

Comment: @AngryOtter what did you import in your code? I used this https://unpkg.com/d3-v6-tip@1.0.6/build/d3-v6-tip.js maybe check theat

Comment: I import the code from the same url, the only working solution for me is to downgrade the d3 version to 5.